# When $f_n \to f$, possible to show that also $\text{ess supp}(f_n) \to \text{ess supp}(f)$?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open and bounded domain. Consider $f, f_n \in L^2(\Omega)$, where $f_n$ is a convergent sequence in the sense:
$$\|f - f_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \varepsilon.$$

Question. Is it true that the essential support of $f_n$ is converging to the essential support of $f$? One can think in terms of:
$$\big| \text{Vol}(\text{ess supp } (f_n)) - \text{Vol}(\text{ess supp } (f)) \big | \leq \delta,$$
It's hard for me to imagine this was not true, but I don't quite know how to show that it is true. I would be happy to get some hints.

Edit: let's assume that $f \neq 0$.

Comment: Just add a spike somewhere, which has low $L^2$ norm despite going up as far as you want

Comment: @ClaudioMoneo, thanks for your answer! I am not entirely sure what are you referring to, could you perhaps elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Please consider rewriting your "convergence in the $L^2$ sense" (or delete it since it's usually known). As it is written currently, it's nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not: consider simply the constant functions $f_n(x) = \frac1n$, for instance.

Comment: I see. Do you think we could somehow exclude the $f=0$ a.e. case? (I edited the question)

Comment: It won't help: $f$ could be a nonzero constant somewhere and $0$ somewhere else, and this type of counterexample could still affect the set on which $f=0$.

Comment: Aha, I understand. Do you think the situation changes if one just considers a Cauchy sequence $\|f_m -f_n\| \leq \varepsilon$ and then tries to establish $|\text{Vol(ess supp(}f_m)) - \text{Vol(ess supp(}f_n))| \leq \delta$?

Comment: It does not change anything: $f_{2n}=0$ and $f_{2n+1}={1\over n}\bf{1}_\Omega.$